# Restrict user deletion from changeset in Elixir and phoenix web application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, delete-row, ecto, changeset

Can we restrict the deletion of a user from database based on his email address in Repo.delete!(changeset) condition in elixir and phoenix web development

This is right now the code which I am using. I want to restrict the deletion of two users from database during deletion:-

```rb
def delete(conn, _params, current_admin) do

    changeset = AdminUser.common_changeset(conn.assigns.admin_user, %{}, whodoneit(current_admin))

    Repo.delete!(changeset)

    msg = gettext("%{name} deleted successfully", name: gettext("Administrator"))

    conn
    |> put_flash(:success, msg)
    |> redirect(to: Routes.admin_admin_user_path(conn, :index))

end
```

Comment: The right way to do it would be to use DB trigger.

Comment: Hi Aleksei...any example if you can post to achieve this task, would be great to me...Thanks.

Comment: I want to restrict the deletion of users with email ids say 'test1@gmail.com' and 'test2@gmail.com'. But I am not sure how to use this in changeset.

Answer (score 2):

Although the proper way to prevent actions on some “stick records” would be to alter the database to reject such modifications (see below,) one still can achieve this result with [`Ecto.Changeset.validate_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_change/3), and its more nailed sibling [`Ecto.Changeset.validate_exclusion/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_exclusion/4). The example there shows how to prevent some changesets to be validated based on the values.

The more general way would be to implement [`Ecto.Repo.delete/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:delete/2) (and [`Ecto.Repo.delete!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:delete!/2)) callbacks to check the values before delegating to the default [`Ecto.Repo.Schema.delete/4`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.4.2/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L276-L278)

```rb
@impl Ecto.Repo
def delete(struct, opts \\ []) do
  # check the record and execute the code below
  #   if and only if the check passed
  Ecto.Repo.Schema.delete(
    __MODULE__,
    get_dynamic_repo(),
    struct,
    with_default_options(:delete, opts)
  )
end
```

It’s still very error-prone because one might simply execute the raw query through [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4)

```rb
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(MyRepo, "DELETE FROM users WHERE email = ", [admin_email])
```

Also, one might *modify* the email and in such a case you’d want to protect against `UPDATE` instead.

---

That said, the only proper way to go would be to rely on the DB to reject such deletions. It can be done with `TRIGGER`, or with `RULE` in PostgreSQL. Here would be the trigger example.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prevent_email_hacks()
  RETURNS "trigger" AS
'
BEGIN
  IF OLD.email = "admin@foo.bar" THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION \'This email is locked\';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER protect_admin
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE prevent_email_hacks();
```

Comment: Congrats on 100k :-)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip thanks, it is not what I am indeed proud of, but still, it’s like “hey, man, 10k times you were helpful.”